# Nomenclature not printing on pdf ouput file

Tags: nomenclature

I've gone through other similar threads concerning this question but the insights did not translate into solution for the problem i'm facing.

I've a custom command defined in the cls file as outlined below:

```
\newcommand{\listofsymbols}{%
  \newpage%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{NOMENCLATURE}%
  \renewcommand{\nomname}{NOMENCLATURE}%
  \printnomenclature%
}
```

I also have the below commands defined in the main tex file.

```
    \usepackage[noprefix]{nomencl}

\makenomenclature
 % ... nomenclature groupings ...
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\medskip \item \textbf{Roman}}{}%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\medskip \item \textbf{Greek}}{}%
   \ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\medskip \item \textbf{Subscripts}}{}%
}
 % ... nomenclature preamble ...
\renewcommand{\nompreamble}{%
\hspace*{-0.50in}\makebox[1.0in][l]{Symbol} Description}
\renewcommand{\nomlabelwidth}{1.0in}
```

I made sure I've this piece of code defined in the associated latexmkrc.tex file as following:

```
################
# nomenclature #
################
add_cus_dep("nlo", "nls", 0, "nlo2nls");
sub nlo2nls {
    system("makeindex $_[0].nlo -s nomencl.ist -o $_[0].nls -t $_[0].nlg");
}
```

But still I don't get the nomenclature printed on the pdf output file. This is executed in Overleaf online with pdfLaTeX as the choice of compiler. Does anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: Try with this definition of sub `nlo2nls`: `{
    system("makeindex -s nomencl.ist -o '$_[0]'.nls '$_[0]'.nlo");
  }`

Comment: @murray it didn't help either. Could you try it at your end and let me know if it works for you though?

Comment: _[Disclaimer: I'm a support personnel at Overleaf.]_ The `latexmkrc` config file should not have any extensions e.g. `.tex`. But Overleaf's default latexmkrc settings already include a rule for handling `nomencl` anyway; see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/How_does_Overleaf_compile_my_project%3F ... so there may be something else in your project that's preventing the nomenclature to be printed. It may be best to contact support@overleaf.com with your project's URL, so that the Support team can have a look.

Comment: @LianTzeLim Yes sure. I've left an email with support at overleaf referring to this post. I look forward to their response. Thanks.

Comment: Ah OK, let me just go through all the messages first. :-)

Answer (score 0):

@LianTze Lim Thank you for your support via email conversation.

I am pasting his response below in the interest of the general public.

"Because Overleaf runs latexmk with the flags -jobname=output -cd, the main .tex file being compiled needs to be on the project's top level, for scripts like makeglossaries, makeindex, texcount (and SyncTeX) to function properly.

Therefore if you re-structure your project, so that template.tex is on the project's top level, things should work without even a custom latexmkrc file."